# GWT. Dynamically adding new columns to CellTable

Tags: java, gwt, celltable

I need allow to user to add new columns to CellTable. Since CellTable require bean class, i can't imagine how to implement it.

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172262/create-gwt-celltable-dynamically