# How to make a Non Editable CellTable?

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform, celltable

I made a dynamic CellTable using this question as guide : [Create GWT CellTable Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172262/create-gwt-celltable-dynamically)

But like that I can only made a editable CellTable, I don't know why.

Check my Code:

```
@UiField
CellTable<List<String>> tableDynamic;
@UiField
SimplePager pagerDynamic;

private SingleSelectionModel<List<String>> 
selectionModelDynamic = new SingleSelectionModel<List<String>>();
private List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
private ListDataProvider<List<String>> providerDynamic 
= new ListDataProvider<List<String>>();
```

My Factory

```
@UiFactory
public CellTable<List<String>> getTabelaDynamic() {
    CellTable<List<String>> table
            = new com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTable<List<String>>();

    //List<String> columnsArray = colunas;
    List<String> columnsArray = columns();
    for (int column = 0; column < columnsArray.size(); column++) {
        table.addColumn(new IndexedColumn(column), new
                TextHeader(columnsArray.get(column)));
    }
    table.setKeyboardSelectionPolicy
 (HasKeyboardSelectionPolicy.KeyboardSelectionPolicy.ENABLED);
    table.setSelectionModel(selectionModelDynamic);
    providerDynamic.addDataDisplay(table);
    providerDynamic.setList(new ArrayList<List<String>>());
    return table;
}
```

Method to get Columns:

```
//Just a static test 
public List<String> columns(){
    colunas.add("Tables");
    return colunas;
}
```

Method for setting data with only one column.

```
@Override
public void setSingleData(List<String> bankData) {
    for (String s : bankData) {
         List<String> help = new ArrayList<String>();
         help.add(s);
         dados.add(help);
    }
    providerDynamic.setList(data);
}
```

I Do a rpc call(onBind method) to get the list and populate on setsingledata method.

Why I'm receiving a editable celltable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table is editable because IndexedColumn uses EditTextCell in the other question. Use TextCell and your table will not be editable.