# Create GWT CellTable Dynamically - sorting

Tags: gwt, celltable, gwt-celltable

Create GWT CellTable Dynamically -

refer to the earlier question : [Create GWT CellTable Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172262/create-gwt-celltable-dynamically/7174272#7174272)

for this dynamic celltable, I would like to do sorting based on a column dynamically.

How to do the comparator ?

My first SO question ! thanks in advance